# AngularJS(1.2.10) ngRoute + Express 3 and Jade doesn't work

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to AngularJS and Node.js(Express 3 and Jade). Currently, I'm trying to make a simple forum with functions such as login, register, posting, and etc.

github link : https://github.com/ggsjyoon/Dat_Asimple_Forum

The base project was created by WebStorm7. I made a navbar on top and put a registration form in AngularUI's Collapse.

In public/javascripts/AngularJSApp.js

```
'use strict';

var SimpleForum = angular.module('SimpleForum', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'SimpleForum.Controllers']);

/**
//AngularJS Routes
SimpleForum.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function     ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/user_list', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/user_list',
            controller: UserListCtrl
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
 */
```

When I un-comment the route block and add 'ngRoute' in dependencies, the Collapse that contains registration form stops working. If I keep the block commented out but just adds 'ngRoute', the Collapse stops working as well. When the route block is commented out and 'ngRoute' is not added in dependencies, the Collapse and all bindings in the registration form work correctly when I click the register button in the navbar.

I followed Brian Ford's example (http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express.html) to make AngularJS' route work, but it didn't resolve the issue. His example was made 2 years ago and it used AngularJS 1.0.3. So I tried to search for similar problems with recent versions, but I couldn't find a solution.

Can somebody take a look at my project on the github and teach me how to fix the issue?

I really tried to fix the issue on my own for 3 days, but I cannot figure this out. Please help me. Let me know if you need more details. I will try to write/upload images/etc.

Thank you.

Edit1 : replaced X.Y.Z with 1.2.10 in views/layout.jade, but the issue is not resolved.

Edit2 : On Console tab - Uncaught Error : [$injector:modulerr].
The Error message image file :
s4.postimg.org/dnoo85y9p/Angular_JS_Error.jpg

Edit3 : Hm, the error message says 'UserListCtrl' is undefined. I have the controller in public/javascripts/Controllers.js

```
angular.module('SimpleForum.Controllers', []).
    //Collapse-able registration form controller.
    controller('CollapseCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        //This property is used for collapse-able div
        $scope.isCollapsed = false;

        //Inputs from the registration form.
        $scope.fNameInput = "";
        $scope.lNameInput = "";
        $scope.eInput = "";
        $scope.ageInput = "";
        $scope.radioModel = "Male";

        //Function which disables the submit button until the form is filled and valid.
        $scope.isDisabled = function () {
            if ($scope.rForm.$invalid) {
                $scope.buttonValue = "Submit Button Disabled";
                //Return true to keep the submit button disabled until form is filled.
                return true;
            } else {
                $scope.buttonValue = "Submit";
                //Enable the Submit button.
                return false;
            }
        };

        $scope.submit = function () {
            //Make a JSON object to send to server side.
            var data = {
                new_first_name: $scope.fNameInput,
                new_last_name: $scope.lNameInput,
                new_email: $scope.eInput,
                new_age: $scope.ageInput,
                new_gender: $scope.radioModel
            };

            //POST method.
            $http.post('/api/register', data).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data.message);
                $scope.clearForm();
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert(data.message);
                });
        };

        //When a user presses the Cancel button or successfully creates a new account, clear the form.
        $scope.clearForm = function () {
            $scope.isCollapsed = false;
            $scope.fNameInput = "";
            $scope.lNameInput = "";
            $scope.eInput = "";
            $scope.ageInput = "";
            $scope.radioModel = "Male";
        };
    }]).
    //User list controller
    controller('UserListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.userList = "";
        $http.get('/api/usersData').success(function (data) {
            $scope.userList = data;
        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing there's an error in your console and that says that ngRoute dependency cannot be resolved.

`ngRoute` is no longer being shipped with AngularJS OOTB. If you want to use it, you have to import `angular-route.js`.

```
<script src="angular.js">
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

[Here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) are the official CDNs.

---

Edit: With the additional details - it seems you're not defining your controller properly. Controller name should be a string.

Modified Code:

```
SimpleForum.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/user_list', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/user_list',
            controller: 'UserListCtrl' // changed
        });  
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: Can you see what the error in the browser console is like? And also, check where angular-route.js is loading properly in the network tab?

Comment: On Console tab - Uncaught Error : [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: I added an image file link of the full error message on the main post. Sorry, I couldn't post more than 1 proper links with a new account.

Comment: Hm, it says 'UserListCtrl' is undefined. I have the controller in public/javascripts/Controllers.js

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code change needed to resolve the error.

Comment: Ah! now it works. I actually had the controller name in '' in AngularJSApp.js file before, but I found some other posts which typed a controller name without '' so I tested it out and forgot to change it back. Basically, Adrian Norman's answer to replace X.Y.Z in layout.jade file and your answer to type a controller name in '' fixed the issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout.jade file you've included:

```
script(src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js")
```

You need to replace 'X.Y.Z' with the version number you're using.

Comment: I replaced X.Y.Z with 1.2.10, but the issue is still there.